# How do I deeplink into an iOS device from the terminal?

Tags: android, ios, iphone

From the terminal machine, I could deeplink into an android device or simulator using

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "myurl"`

For iOS, the below could deeplink into the Simulator

`xcrun simctl openurl booted "myurl"`

What about for iOS devices connecting to terminal? I search and can't find anywhere stated.